# Undefined index encrypter.php after admin login in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/Registration/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 588

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: Is that comes after upgrading or after installation of new Magento? Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir php version is 7.2

Comment: @HarshJayswal i am using magento 2.3. i am working on Extension devolpment. when i install magento 2.3 everything is working fine. but now admin login is not working but admin login page is displayed but when i enter login credential it gave me exception of undefined index .i have also tried it on php version 7.1 but facing the same exception

Answer (score 1):

ok got your problem just create a new admin user using the following command

```
bin/magento admin:user:create
```

after that login with new admin id it will solve your problem.

Comment: it does not solve my problem

Comment: i have Migrated My Site from Magneto Cloud to AWS Server and this Solution Helped me 

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your environment is using `ARGON2ID13` instead of `SHA256` for hashing.

Check if you have '`sodium`' php extension enabled.

If you disable the `libsodium` php extension, it will fallback on `SHA-256` and won't break Magento.

In the Docker php-fpm image you can comment it out in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini`:

```
;extension=sodium.so
```

Comment: the senerio is i devolped extension on magento 2.3 and for testing of extension i insall magento 2.2.9 and extension behave excellent but after tesing when i want to login on magento 2.3 admin pannel it gave me this exception.does it resolved by installing sodium extension?

Comment: not install, you need to disable sodium extension

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23511#issuecomment-507033705

Comment: How to check this extension is enable?

Comment: i have read this issue on provided link but here only describe its a PHP version issue but its not a PHP issue because i have have checked it by change PHP version

Comment: It's not just php issue, its conflict of php with magento 2.3. Since you are using php version 7.2 then there is no version issue, only sodium extension that needs to be disable

Comment: Can you plese list the coomand for disable it ?

Comment: are you using ubuntu with php or ubuntu with php-fpm? or anything else?

Comment: ubunto with php

Comment: I don't know exactly if it would work but try this command `phpdismod sodium`

Comment: Tried before but it not solve my problem